# Partially skip characters in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr

I'm trying to match the following phrase:

```
<svg/onload="alert(1);">
```

And I need the tokens to be like:

```
'<svg', 'onload="alert(1);", '>'
```

So basically I need to skip the `/` in the `<svg/onload` part. But the `skip` phrase is not allowed here:

```
Attribute
    : ('/' -> skip) Identifier '=' StringLiteral?
    ;
```

The error was

```
error(133): HTML.g4:35:11: ->command in lexer rule Attribute must be last element of single outermost alt
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The error message pretty much tells you what the problem is. The `skip` command has to be at the end of the rule. You cannot skip intermediate tokens, but only entire rules.

However, I wonder why you want to skip the slash. Why not just let the lexer scan everything (it has to anyway) and then ignore the tokens you don't need? Also I wouldn't use a lexer rule, but a parser rule, to allow arbitrary spaces between elements.

Answer (score -1):

Try lexer's `setText(getText().replace("/", ""))` or any other matched string manipulation